# "pwd" command will work all linux type of linux?

Tags: linux

I have .sh file to run application. In that file, I want to set server name dynamically instead of configuring every time.

I tried the following and it is working fine in CentOS.

```
nohup /voip/java/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/java -server  -Xss256k -Xms500m -Xmx500m -DServerName=`pwd`/application com.application
```

But will it work with all type of the Linux and Unix version?? (sorry, I am beginner to Linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's part of the core commands: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GNU_Core_Utilities_commands

As such, it will work with all GNU/Linux. It is also part of the Unix usual commands.